# Pytorch lightning: 'CIFAR10DataModule' object has no attribute 'train_loader'

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning

Would you tell me why I failed to import CUFAR10DataModule()?

At first, I run the code on GoogleColab,

```
from pl_bolts.datamodules import CIFAR10DataModule
dm = CIFAR10DataModule()
```

then, the code was performed for the confirmation

```
from torch.optim import Adam
optimizer = Adam(finetune_layer.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

for epoch in range(10):
  for batch in dm.train_loader:
    x, y = batch
    with torch.no_grad():
      features = backbone(x)

    preds = finetune_layer(features)
    loss = cross_entropy(preds, y)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(loss.item())
```

However, the message `AttributeError: 'CIFAR10DataModule' object has no attribute 'train_loader'` was returned after running the code.

When the code was run to confirm the `dm`,

```
for batch in dm.train_dataloader:
  x, y = batch
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
  break
```

The error says `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`.

The code looks the same with an example, but I wonder why such an error was generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

First, the way you get the underlying PyTorch dataloader is `dm.train_dataloader()` not `dm.train_loader`. It is a *function, not a property*.

```
for batch in dm.train_dataloader():
    x, y = batch
    ...
```

Secondly, since you are trying to use a `LightningDataModule` without a `Trainer`, you need to manually invoke

```
dm.prepare_data()
dm.setup()
```

.. in order for the dataloader to be available via `.train_dataloader()`.